# FileNotFoundException on ExternalStorage, although I have rights to read and write

Tags: java, android, ioexception

here's my problem:
I tried like 10 different solutions now, and it still won't work.

I want to download a PDF File from the internet and then save it to external storage.

What I've done:
 - Added INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE "Uses Permissions"
 - Tried with Emulator, as well as Galaxy Nexus plugged in and plugged off

That's my doInBackground download method:

```
26    @Override
27    protected String doInBackground(String... downloadUrl) {
28      if (!mediaIsAvailable()) return null;
29
30      final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 23;
31      String url              = downloadUrl[0];
32      String target_filename  = downloadUrl[1];
33      String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
34      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
35
36      try {
37          File targetDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
38          if(!targetDir.exists())
39          {
40              targetDir.mkdirs();
41          }
42
43          File file = new File(targetDir, target_filename);
44          URL urlObj = new URL(url);
45          URLConnection connection = urlObj.openConnection();
46
47          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
48
49          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
50          byte[] bArray = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
51          int current = 0;
52          int read = 0;
53          while(current != -1)
54          {
55              fos.write(bArray,0,current);
56              current = bis.read(bArray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
57              read = read + current;
58          }
59          fos.close();
60          bis.close();
61          notificationManager.cancel(1);
62      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
63          e.printStackTrace();
64      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
65          e.printStackTrace();
66      } catch (IOException e) {
67          e.printStackTrace();
68      }
69      return null;
70    }
```

and that's the Exception I get:

```
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Download/speiseplan-rosenheim.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at de.fhrosenheim.app.campus.helpers.DownloadFileHelper.doInBackground(DownloadFileHelper.java:49)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at de.fhrosenheim.app.campus.helpers.DownloadFileHelper.doInBackground(DownloadFileHelper.java:1)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-10 08:31:17.861: W/System.err(23054):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
05-10 08:31:17.868: W/System.err(23054):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which one is 49 line in DownloadFileHelper.java?

Comment: Hey, i added line Numbers to the thread above :)

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a chance, that there was "WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" as a permission instead of the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" i added VIA THE PERMISSIONS GUI? I don't know why that happened, but I fixed the xml and it now works. Thank you guys anyways

Comment: Yes on debugging I got libcore.io.ErrnoException and which means there is problem in accessing the directory/file.

Answer (score 2):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /mnt/sdcard/Download/speiseplan-rosenheim.pdf: open failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)

```
File targetDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
```

try

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "Download";
```

and

```
File file = new File(path, target_filename);
```